# How to declare dependencies for my Module::Starter module?

Tags: perl, cpan

I've started writing a Perl module with `module-starter`. Now, I've found that it will depend on a non-core module. Where should I note this dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module-starter` creatures an installer (`Makefile.PL`) that uses [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker). You'll need to add

```
PREREQ_PM => {
    'Some::Prereq' => 0,
},
```

to argument list of the call to `WriteMakefile` therein.